# Reshape from unconstructed dataset in r

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape a dataset by switching some cells information. Here is how my sample dataset looks like.

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c("Text","A","B","C","D"),
               var2 = c("Text",NA, 1,0,1),
               var3 = c("112-1",NA,NA,"text",NA),
               var4 = c("Text",1,0,NA, NA),
               var5 = c("113-1",NA,"text",NA,NA))
> data
  var1 var2  var3 var4  var5
1 Text Text 112-1 Text 113-1
2    A <NA>  <NA>    1  <NA>
3    B    1  <NA>    0  text
4    C    0  text <NA>  <NA>
5    D    1  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
```

It needs some cleaning first.`var1` has the `item` information.  `var2` and `var4` have score information. `var3` and `var5` have `id` information at the first row.
I will need to reshape this dataset as below.

```
> data.1
   id  A B  C  D
1 112 NA 1  0  1
2 113  1 0 NA NA
```

Considering this datafile in multiple columns (e.g. having more columns var6,var7,var8,var9,.etc) with the same pattern, How can I reshape to this desired dataset?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much different from my answer yesterday, but this will give you the result you asked for. Shift that first row over one column so that the id is on the same column with the needed values, remove the unnecessary columns, then make row one the column names. Add some pivots and then it should be roughly what you need:

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c("Text","A","B","C","D"), var2 = c("Text",NA, 1,0,1), var3 = c("112",NA,NA,NA,NA), var4 = c("Text",1,0,NA, NA), var5 = c(113,NA,NA,NA,NA))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data2<-data%>%
  mutate_all(as.character) #Making character to avoid factor issues

data2[1, 2:(ncol(data2) - 1)] <- data2[1, 3:ncol(data2)] #Shifting first row over one column

data3<-data2%>%
  select(-var3,-var5) #Removing the uneeded columns

colnames(data3) <- data3[1,] #Taking the first row and making it the column names
data3 <- data3[-1, ] #removing row 1, since it was made into column names


data3%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Text, names_to = "id", values_to = "time")%>% #Making the data into longer format
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Text, values_from = time) #Then back into wide
```

Comment: how can I automate this part? `data3<-data2%>%
  select(-var3,-var5) #Removing the unneeded columns` since there will be multiple unnecessary columns.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what your data looks like. With the test set, they always have four NA's, so maybe filter columns where there are four NAs? If it's always odd numbered columns, it could be something like for the length of your data, remove all odds so var3, 5, 7, 9 etc. Those were my first thoughts, but again it might change pending your data!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

#First rename the columns to more appropriate
n = 2 #Number of pairs of columns you have (here 2)
nam <- do.call(paste0, (expand.grid(c("n_", "id_"), seq(n))))
colnames(data) <- c("col", nam)

#Then, the data manipulation
data %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("id"), ~ first(str_remove(.x, "-")))) %>% 
  fill(starts_with("id")) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-col, names_to = c(".value", "rn"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col", values_from = 'n') %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

```r
  id    A     B     C     D    
1 1121  NA    1     0     1    
2 1131  1     0     NA    NA
```

Comment: sometimes there are other values in the `id` column. this line stops replicating the first row and start copying the other value down `mutate(across(starts_with("id"), as.numeric)) %>%`. How can this part copy only the first row?

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. If this does not work, it's better to add another version of the data set where this answer does not work.

Comment: I just modified the sample dataset and converted the `id` as character.

Comment: It really depends on how your string is formatted, but for instance I use `str_extract` to extract the first batch of digits. See my eidt.

Comment: how can we remove `-` s and keep the numbers only for the `id`? I might need the whole numbers.

Comment: You can use `str_remove`, see edit

Answer (score 0):

You could shift the first row, delete, columns %% 2 and `t`ranspose.

```
data[1, ] <- data[1, -1]
data <- data[c(TRUE, seq_len(ncol(data))[-1] %% 2 == 0)]
setNames(as.data.frame(t(data[, -1]), row.names=FALSE), c('id', data[[1]][-1])) |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
#      id  A B  C  D
# 1 112-1 NA 1  0  1
# 2 113-1  1 0 NA NA
```

BTW, how do you get such data? Maybe you have an [x-y-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).